# python dynamic import and module type support

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, annotations, pymongo, type-hinting

I'm working on a python package which could support multiple orm modules at the same time.
The issue is coming during providing static type checks.
As it could support multiple modules defining type checks for same variable has become hard.

I have a file named typing where I'm collecting all my type variables and import these types from here (Don't yet know if this decision is right or wrong.)

The issue is maybe a user could have let's say for example installed sqlalchemy or another user have installed pymongo who will use my package.

How would I go defining type hint for a method which receive an object of these classes depending upon installed module?

How I'm currently thinking about handling it(just an example not the real deal so kindly ignore the object_type):

```
try:
    from sqlalchemy.orm.decl_api import DeclarativeMeta
    HAS_SQLALCHEMY=True
except ImportError:
    HAS_SQLALCHEMY=False

try:
    from pymongo import Server
    HAS_PYMONGO=True
except ImportError:
    HAS_PYMONGO=False
    
if HAS_PYMONGO:
    object_type = Server

if HAS_SQLALCHEMY:
    object_type = DeclarativeMeta
```

then when i import object_type from typing file it atleast shows correct import and method access hints in ide (pycharm) if anyone of these orm modules are installed
**what I'm trying to know**
Is this a bad way of defining type hints? if so then what would an appropriate way to go about doing this?
Type hints helps a user to pass right method params and static type checker saves alot of time in debugging that's why I'm putting alot of thought into this.

Comment: Have you considered `TypeVar`s?

Comment: Yes I tried using it but whenever I tried to use the same name more than once it sent a static error that same name must only be defined once.